# Sort a HashSet by value in java

Tags: java, sorting, hashset

Is there a method that comes with HashSet that allows it to sort itself, instead of writing an algorithm to sort it? I know the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html has an Iterator, but how is that actually implemented?

Comment: why not just use `TreeSet`

Comment: A `HashSet` doesn't have an order. That is clearly stated in the javadoc.

Comment: Or a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is designed for iteration.

Comment: @jigar for an assignment I am supposed to use a hashset, I've already used a treeset to do the same thing

Comment: Add its elements to a `List` and sort that.

Comment: I think it's a trick question by your teacher. The answer is: Use a TreeSet instead.

Comment: Possibly the teacher doesn't understand what they're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet`'s iterator is not sorted because it just outputs the bins as-is. In fact, changing the implementation of the class, the load factor or any of the other parameters almost always changes the order of the iterator. However, you can wrap the set values in a `List` and sort them using `Collections.sort(List)` or `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
...
HashSet<? extends Comparable> myHashSet = ...;
...
List<? extends Comparable> sortedList = Arrays.asList(myHashSet.toArray(new Comparable[0]));
Collections.sort(sortedList);
```

Comment: Would this mess up any duplicates in the set?

Comment: @user2920965 Won't as far as I know, but read the docs to make sure.

Comment: Pending +1, but this example doesn't compile. `Collection#toArray` returns an `Object[]`, and `Object` isn't comparable, so you can't sort it. You need to pass in an array of the correct type. Note that you can't create an array as `new T[]` due to erasure.

Comment: @yshavit. I do not intend to make the example compile since that would just distract from the answer. However, good point about not assigning the correct output type.

Comment: This answer is better. One thing to note is that `Collections.sort` doesn't return anything, it does an in-place sort on the `List<T>` it's given. In this example, you don't ever save a reference to that `List<T>`, so the sorting is done on a list that nobody (other than `Collections.sort`) ever sees.

Comment: @yshavit I see you will not allow me to post a hastily concocted answer. I appreciate it.